# Categories show only childrem

Tags: categories, gwcode-categories, children

is there a trick to only showing ONLY the children of a certain category?

```
{exp:gwcode_catmenu show="5" cat_id="5"}
<a href="{path='catmenu-demo/example1/{complete_path}'}"{cat_name}</a>
{/exp:gwcode_catmenu}
```

Trying to only show the children of cat 5, all parent categories are showing as well as the children of 5

```
-Bestseller
-New
-Featured
-Hunting (id 5)
----Accessories
----Calls
----Cameras
----Decoys
----Bags/Cases
----Face Paint / Scent Elimination
----Knives
----Deer Scents
----Range Finders / GPS
----Videos
-Fishing
-Archery
-Shooting
-Clothing
-Footwear
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the cat_id="" parameter. This will show child categories for that category ID.

Comment: that does show the children for 5 but it also shows all other parents categories as well even if I add show="5".  IT also shows the parent category I only want the children as per my original question

Comment: Anything below category 5 in your example would be considered child categories. Are you saying you're also getting results for categories above cat 5 in the hierarchy? Can you provide an example catergory list you're working with and identify the categories you're looking to isolate?

Comment: {exp:gwcode_catmenu style="linear" show="5" cat_id="5"}
    <li><a href="{path='Products'}">{cat_name}</a></li>
{/exp:gwcode_catmenu}

-Bestseller
-New
-Featured
-Hunting
----Accessories
----Calls
----Cameras
----Decoys
----Bags/Cases
----Face Paint / Scent Elimination
----Knives
----Deer Scents
----Range Finders / GPS
----Videos
-Fishing
-Archery
-Shooting
-Clothing
-Footwear

Comment: anyone have any advice

Comment: Try adding active_branch_only="yes" as a parameter. That should eliminate any parent categories.

Comment: thanks that does get rid of the other categories!!  But I am still getting the parent and then the children.  Any way t o get rid of the parent and just display the children?

Comment: You can probably do an if conditional to check the cat_id before outputting the link. For example, {if cat_id == 5}Menu{/if} will replace the "Hunting" with "Menu". Alternatively if you don't want it at all, just put: {exp:gwcode_catmenu style="linear" show="5" cat_id="5"} {if cat_id != 5}<li><a href="{path='Products'}">{cat_name}</a></li>{/if} {/exp:gwcode_catmenu}